# Magento - Customer login won't work on Onepage Checkout after 1.8.1 update from 1.7

Tags: magento

After updating Magento from 1.7 to 1.8.1, I found myself correcting most of the `formkey` issues on my custom theme. I think everything now works correctly except for one thing: the customer login on the onepage checkout page doesn't seem to do anything. The problem seems really odd to me since the customer login works everywhere else on the site.

I use a module (Crius SkipStep1) to skip the first step and instead show the guest billing & shipping method first (with possibility of switching to the login system if wanted). 
Using it or the default login system doesn't seem to do any difference; the problem is there in both cases. After login, the page reloads but doesn't show me anything more than before.

With the module, the `checkout/onepage/saveMethod/` function runs after the page reloads. Without the module, nothing happens. In both cases, I can still do the guest checkout method without any issue.

And the odd thing is that if I type the password wrong, the page reloads normally and the error message for incorrect password shows up. I tried testing the default and base themes, and the problem occurs anyway despite the template files being up to date.

I think I tried everything and don't see what to do anymore, so I need help from fresh eyes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem. You need to add `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>` after the `<form>` tag in the following files:

```
/app/design/frontend/../template/persistent/checkout/onepage/login.phtml
/app/design/frontend/../template/checkout/onepage/login.phtml
```

That should fix your login issue.

Comment: Thank you for the additional note about the "persistent" directory.

Answer (score 1):

Added `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>` in the login forms of the checkout section and there you go. My issue was fixed.